How to install Pangolin in Windows 11/GLEW
I have this issue. The cmake doesn't see the GLEW
Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22621.0 to target Windows 10.0.22631.
The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.40.33811.0
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.40.33811.0
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.40.33807/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
Detecting C compile features
Detecting C compile features - done
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.40.33807/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Config.cmake:20 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Targets.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  components/pango_geometry/CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:111 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Config.cmake:20 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Targets.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  components/pango_image/CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:111 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Config.cmake:20 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Targets.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  components/pango_opengl/CMakeLists.txt:25 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:111 (include)


Found Eigen: 'C://include/eigen3'
Found OpenGL: opengl32
Found GLEW: C:/Program Files/GLEW/lib
pybind11 v2.12.0 
Selected Python: 'C:/Users/Apollo/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe'. cmake --build . -t pypangolin_pip_install to use pypangolin module.
Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
MediaFoundation Found and Enabled
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Config.cmake:20 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Targets.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.30/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake:76 (find_package)
  build/PangolinConfig.cmake:14 (find_dependency)
  examples/BasicOpenGL/CMakeLists.txt:2 (find_package)


Found OpenGL: opengl32  found components: OpenGL
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Config.cmake:20 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Targets.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.30/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake:76 (find_package)
  build/PangolinConfig.cmake:14 (find_dependency)
  examples/HelloPangolin/CMakeLists.txt:2 (find_package)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Config.cmake:20 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Targets.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.30/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake:76 (find_package)
  build/PangolinConfig.cmake:14 (find_dependency)
  examples/HelloPangolinThreads/CMakeLists.txt:2 (find_package)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Config.cmake:20 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Targets.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.30/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake:76 (find_package)
  build/PangolinConfig.cmake:14 (find_dependency)
  examples/SimpleDisplay/CMakeLists.txt:2 (find_package)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Config.cmake:20 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Targets.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.30/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake:76 (find_package)
  build/PangolinConfig.cmake:14 (find_dependency)
  examples/SimpleMultiDisplay/CMakeLists.txt:2 (find_package)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Config.cmake:20 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Targets.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.30/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake:76 (find_package)
  build/PangolinConfig.cmake:14 (find_dependency)
  examples/SimpleDisplayImage/CMakeLists.txt:2 (find_package)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Config.cmake:20 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Targets.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.30/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake:76 (find_package)
  build/PangolinConfig.cmake:14 (find_dependency)
  examples/SimplePlot/CMakeLists.txt:2 (find_package)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Config.cmake:20 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Targets.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.30/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake:76 (find_package)
  build/PangolinConfig.cmake:14 (find_dependency)
  examples/SimpleVideo/CMakeLists.txt:2 (find_package)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Config.cmake:20 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Targets.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.30/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake:76 (find_package)
  build/PangolinConfig.cmake:14 (find_dependency)
  examples/SimpleRecord/CMakeLists.txt:2 (find_package)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Config.cmake:20 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Targets.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.30/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake:76 (find_package)
  build/PangolinConfig.cmake:14 (find_dependency)
  examples/HelloPangolinOffscreen/CMakeLists.txt:2 (find_package)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Config.cmake:20 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Targets.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.30/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake:76 (find_package)
  build/PangolinConfig.cmake:14 (find_dependency)
  examples/SimpleScene/CMakeLists.txt:2 (find_package)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Config.cmake:20 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Targets.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.30/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake:76 (find_package)
  build/PangolinConfig.cmake:14 (find_dependency)
  tools/VideoConvert/CMakeLists.txt:2 (find_package)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Config.cmake:20 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Targets.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.30/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake:76 (find_package)
  build/PangolinConfig.cmake:14 (find_dependency)
  tools/VideoJson/CMakeLists.txt:2 (find_package)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Config.cmake:20 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Targets.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.30/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake:76 (find_package)
  build/PangolinConfig.cmake:14 (find_dependency)
  tools/Plotter/CMakeLists.txt:2 (find_package)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Config.cmake:20 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Targets.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.30/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake:76 (find_package)
  build/PangolinConfig.cmake:14 (find_dependency)
  tools/VideoViewer/CMakeLists.txt:2 (find_package)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Config.cmake:20 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    C:/Program Files/Eigen/build/Eigen3Targets.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.30/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake:76 (find_package)
  build/PangolinConfig.cmake:14 (find_dependency)
  tools/ModelViewer/CMakeLists.txt:2 (find_package)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Thank you and have a great day

I was able to get Pangolin working on Windows 11 using Visual Studio and vcpkg. I did not try using a CMake-based workflow, nor did I try building the pieces from source.

Install pangolin: vcpkg install pangolin
Install glew: vcpkg install glew
In the Visual Studio project properties, add an Additional Include Directory that points to your glew include directory. For example I used C:\dev\cpp\vcpkg\packages\glew_x64-windows\include but obviously utilize your own path.

Then to build and run on Windows you must include pangolin as follows:
#define NOMINMAX
#include <windows.h>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <cmath>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <pangolin/pangolin.h>

With the above steps I am able to build and run Pangolin-based C++ code examples.
